# What will be the right algorithm to bottom up parse and reduce a parse tree?

Tags: tree, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree, traversal, parse-tree

The example parse tree is for the expression

```
IF( ABS( column ) > 10 ,"8214","8215")
```

inorder to reduce it to an AST having nodes (user-defined) of only QueryFunction (ABS, IF), QueryColumns (column), QueryConstants (10 ,"8214","8215") like

```
                    IF
                    |
     |--------------|--------------| 
     >            "8214"         "8215"
|----|----|
ABS       10
|
columnName
```

What will be the right algorithm to use ? Is a complex parsing approach like LR parsing required in this case ?

Please note that the QueryFunction can have various number of parameters depending on the type of function. Also each function can have other nested functions within it.

[image: Parse Tree Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing particularly "complex" about doing this.  It's fairly common for ANTLR users to want to transform the parse tree to an AST (especially, given all the intermediate odes a parse tree contains).

With an ANTLR Listener (or visitor), it's relatively simple to visit the parse tree and use it to construct whatever structure of AST you need.

Unless you *KNOW* you need an AST, you may wish to try the native Listeners/Visitors that ANTLR produces.  By overriding the `*BaseListener` or `*BaseVisitor` classes, you get default implementations for all of your nodes that allow you to write code that may safely "ignore" the intermediate nodes you don't really care about, and just "listen in" on the nodes you do care about (for listeners).  (you'd want to understand this if you want to use them to create an AST regardless, so no wasted learning).

NB: whatever grammar you're using looks like it could use some refinement. The very bottom if the graph is an example of what I'm talking about.  The `column_name` parse rule should either be a Token or refer to a Token rule for pulling the column name into a single token instead of a list of characters.  With a more appropriate grammar, your ANTLR parse tree will seem much less ridiculous (and easier to work with for generating an AST if you need).

Comment: Thank you for the Suggestion. Can you please add any references for reducing the trees by overriding the *BaseListener or *BaseVisitor classes in to your answer.

Comment: Regarding the grammar, Column name is always going to be any alphanumeric combination, how can that be represented as one token if we don't know the value upfront ?

Comment: re: the column name.  It's likely that this should be something like an NAME token in your grammar (say "NAME: [a-z-A-Z-0-9]+;"). Be sure and place it after any keywords it might match.  Then you could use the NAME token anywhere you have a 'name_reference' in your parser rules.  This change alone would significantly simplify the sample tree you've shown.  (Looking at it farther, it seems you probably need a WHITESPACE lexer rule with either a "-> skip" or "-> channel(HIDDEN)" directive (allowing you to skip ignore whitespace in your parser rules.

Comment: After looking more at your parse tree, I think you will benefit from something like the ANTLR Mega Tutorial (https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/) and/or the the Pragmatic Programmers "The Definitive ANTLR4 Reference".  Your question suggests you're undertaking a reasonably substantial project, bu the tree suggests you'd benefit from a better understanding of ANTLR fundamentals.